# Wordpress Custom Page Template based on URL Rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I've a problem with creating Custom Page Template based on URL Rewrite.

This is my rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/var1', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&var1=yes', 'top' );
```

And this is how I adding custom template to this url:

```
    if ( get_query_var( 'var1' ) ) {
    include( get_template_directory() . '/cat-var1.php' );}
```

It works, but when I scroll down the page I see content from parent page in this case it's current category.

So page show content from page var1 and after it content from parent page, how to delete content of parent page?

This is my full code:

```
 function prefix_movie_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/var1', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&var1=yes', 'top' );}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_movie_rewrite_rule' );

function prefix_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'var1';
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'prefix_register_query_var' );

function prefix_url_rewrite_templates() {

    if ( get_query_var( 'var1' ) ) {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/cat-var1.php' );
    }
}



add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_url_rewrite_templates' );
```

Regards

Comment: Add else part and put default template in that condition.

Comment: i don't know what does it mean?

Comment: you are just adding your template into the other template

Comment: you need either a template redirect, or a template_include filter

Comment: either : `add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_callback' );` or : `add_action( 'template_include', 'my_callback' );`

Comment: it can't be this cause i have it in my code

Comment: @adkoski you should better use the `template_include` filter. Otherwise, you should add `exit;` after the `include( get_template_directory() . '/cat-var1.php' );` to prevent the default template from being loaded which likely displays the "parent page".